# Launching Android/iOS apps from browser

Tags: android, ios, uri-scheme, data-uri-scheme

I have read a lot of similar questions but none seem to answer directly my issue. I am working on a project and want to implement a way to launch 3rd party apps from within a web app. I have found SOME URISchemes and got these launching fine on iOS and some on Android devices by looking in the info.plist file. I have noticed however that a LOT of apps, (most of the ones I've tested to be honest) don't have a URIScheme that I can find to launch the app (I may be looking in the wrong place). There is not really a set list of apps I want to launch, as this will be differ when it is being used by different people. I really would like the ability to launch ANY app installed on the phone/tablet. All the web app will do is link to a database I create as I get feedback from those editing and using the web app which I will manage.

So my question is this, how can I launch ANY app from within the web app?

Apps I'm looking at are not on lists like http://handleopenurl.com/scheme etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least on Android, there is no guaranteed solution. You are welcome to try to use `intent` scheme URLs to open the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activity for a given application ID. However, you cannot force all browser developers to honor that scheme. You also have no way to determine if the app is installed and available to the current user, and so clicking the link may crash or pop an error dialog or something.

Comment: There is no solution for this on iOS either apart from what you are already doing which is opening a known URL scheme

Comment: This is what I have been finding so thought I would ask on here in case someone had found something new or different. Hmm will have to try to sort something out with this. With regards to the app not being installed, if it isn't on the device it pops up an error message saying it is not installed. As this will be being used by trained people they will be made aware that to launch an app it needs to be installed. Obvious to us, but not to some people. Thanks for the input though, much appreciated.